# How to create a new group of character array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have data stored in text files.The data is in 'cell array of string' after read it using *textscan* and contains various of colour name. Below is the content of my data:

```
name of colour        
'lavender'           
'lavenderblush'       
'lemonchiffon'        
'lightblue'           
'lightcoral'             
'lightcyan'
```

I want to create new array to group all color characters into the main color only (red, blue, orange, brown,etc).
I am really struggling to solve this problem. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
load_data = fopen('result.txt', 'r');
C = textscan(load_data, ' %s ');
fclose(load_data);
name = C{1,1};
group = char(name)
if group{:,1} == lavender
    fprintf('purple');
else 
    fprintf('nothing');
end
```

This is my code but if I run this, always get error

> Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Comment: But what is your problem: the classification (lavender -> blue, lemon -> green....) or how to structure your data ? Did you also have the RGB (or HSV, or something else) vector of your colors ?

Comment: If you create an array of char or string, they all have to be of the same size. E.g.: Nx10, where 10 is the length of string/char.

Comment: @Cassio what about `myarray = ['a';'ab'] ;` ?

Comment: @obchardon: That doesn't work.

Comment: @Cassio, I use Octave but I think that matlab have the same behaviour: Octave auto-fill a string with blank space if there is another string which is longer.

Comment: @obchardon : yeah..I want to class the name of colour into new group of colour (lavender->purple, lemonchiffon ->yellow).

Comment: @obchardon: >> myarray = ['a';'ab'] ;
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: you want to use {} instead of [] for cell arrays

Comment: load_data = fopen('result.txt', 'r');
C = textscan(load_data, ' %s ');
fclose(load_data);
name = C{1,1};
group = char(name)
if group{:,1} == lavender
    fprintf('purple');
else
    fprintf('nothing');
end . This is my code but if I run this, always get error 'Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.'

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is fairly clear. Once you have called `char(name)`, you are working with a regular character array (i.e. a string) and no longer a cell array. Braces (i.e. `{}`) are used to index cell arrays so you should instead be using parentheses (i.e. `()`). Note this actually happens as soon as you index using `{}` so `C{1,1}` would actually return a string already and the `char` line is thus redundant:

```
if group(:,1) == lavender
```

I suspect you actually want something more like

```
name = C{1};
group = char(name) %this line is redundant because C{1} already extracts a string
if strcmp(group,lavender)
    fprintf('purple');
else 
    fprintf('nothing');
end
```

but it's impossible to say since you did not define the variable `lavender`.

I would also question what data structure you intend to use. I'm going to assume you actually have some way of categorizing the colours? I'm going to assume this is manual in which case I would suggest converting your txt file to a csv file and putting your manual colour categories as a second column but I'll leave the implementation details to you.

Lets say you have 3 colour categories for now, `'purple'`, `'blue'`, and `'orange'`, my suggestion is to use a logical matrix that has 3 columns (1 per colour category) and `n` rows where `n` is the number of rows in your text file (i.e. the number of colours you need to categorize).

Now I'm going to assume you have some sort of mapping function that can categorize your colours so `map('lavender')` returns `'purple'` and `map('lightcyan')` returns `'blue'`

First we should make a cell array of categories that we can use to map the category string to its column number:

```
categories = {'purple'
              'blue'
              'orange'}
```

and the result will go in the logical matrix `categorized`

```
load_data = fopen('result.txt', 'r'); 
C = textscan(load_data, ' %s ');  
fclose(load_data);

n = numel(C);
categories = {'purple'
              'blue'
              'orange'};
categorized = false(n, numel(categories)); %preallocation

for row = 1:n
    colour = C{row};
    category = map(colour); %you need to implement this map function yourself.
    categorized(row, strcmp(category, categories)) = true;
end
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work unless compensating for extra blank characters that are added to a char in a char array, since a char array in Matlab has to have the same dimensions in columns. So even if a string has 10 characters, in the example above it will have 15, to compensate for the largest string in that char array, it's not only unlikely that the creator of the question is doing this, but also highly unpractical. It is better to avoid conversion to char array and keep it in the cell array.

Comment: @Cassio if you read the answer, I state that the `char` line actually does nothing since the way OP coded it, it is operating on a string and not a cell array. So the code does work, but the `group = char...` line is pointless. In fact the entire problem is pointless which is why I have written some actually useful code below

Comment: Thank you so much, Cassio and @Dan for your great explanation. I want to ask Dan, what do you mean by putting manual colour categories as a second column?Is it I need to manually write the colour of ' purple' beside 'lavender' column in CSV file?Or is it another way.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment above, I assume you're having trouble with your code, not actually with the sorting of colors, or how to categorize them.

1. `group` is not a Cell array, it's a Char array. So in order to access its values you should use `group(:,1)` instead of `group{:,1}`
2. Remember that the number of columns in `group` is the number of characters in that line, normalized to the number of characters of the largest string in that set. So 2 issues here:

   - You can't use `group(:,1)`, as it will get the first character of all the strings in that array. You should get the entire line for that string `group(1,:)`. *NB: I say **string** for simplicity, it's actually a char array*.
   - `'lavender'` has only 10 characters, but it will have 15, as per the largest string. So the string comparison doesn't quite work, unless you add the extra blank spaces to compensate

You can try out the code below:

```
load_data = fopen('result.txt', 'r'); 
C = textscan(load_data, ' %s ');  
fclose(load_data);  
name = C{1,1};  
if name{1,:} == '''lavender'''
    fprintf('purple');  
else
    fprintf('nothing'); 
end
```

I assume that your TXT file actually has the string *'lavender'*, in this case I used character escape *'''lavender'''*.

Comment: In this line `if name{1,:} == '''lavender'''` you should use `all` i.e. `if all(name{1,:} == '''lavender''')` or better yet just use `strcmp`